# Keeping CSS counters the same after removing associated elements

Tags: html, css, list, css-counter

I have a CSS counter that counts my list items and adds the number to the ::before content, however when I remove a certain list element, the numbers shift to reflect an accurate list numbering. I don't want the numbers to change after removing one that is using the counter. This is some example code of my problem:

```js
function remove() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("list-item")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.number-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: list-count 0;
}

.list-item {
  counter-increment: list-count 1;
}

.list-item::before {
  content: counter(list-count) ". ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="number-list">
    <li class="list-item">Canada</li>
    <li class="list-item">The U.S.A.</li>
    <li class="list-item">Mexico</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="remove()">Set first list item display to none</button>
</div>
```

I tried messing around with the counters but to no avail. Any solutions?

Comment: Would setting height to 0 and overflow to hidden work for your example? I think js might be the best route for setting numbers to things, depending on your end goal, but changing the height and overflow would make the css still count it but collapse it to give the illusion of being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dynamic set of list items, you could consider setting their counter value with JavaScript with [`counter-set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-set) so that the counter value does not depend on any previous sibling elements.

```js
function remove() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("list-item")[0].style.display = "none";
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('.number-list > .list-item')
  .forEach((item, i) => {
    item.style.counterSet = `list-count ${i + 1}`;
  });
```

```css
.number-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  counter-reset: list-count 0;
}

.list-item {
  counter-increment: list-count 1;
}

.list-item::before {
  content: counter(list-count) ". ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="number-list">
    <li class="list-item">Canada</li>
    <li class="list-item">The U.S.A.</li>
    <li class="list-item">Mexico</li>
  </ul>
  <button onclick="remove()">Set first list item display to none</button>
</div>
```